# Error when checking target: expected dense_3 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (10, 10, 2)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I have 128x128 RGB Images  shaped `(n,128,128,3)`, with `(n,10,2)` shaped labels.
This is my code for the neural network:

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import InputLayer
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import  MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Conv2D, Dense, Flatten
from tensorflow.python.keras.optimizers import Adam

from data_gen import gen_dataset
data, labels = gen_dataset(10)
test_data, test_labels = gen_dataset(10)

model = Sequential()

print(data.shape) # (10, 128, 128, 3)
print(labels.shape) # (10, 10, 2)

model.add(InputLayer(input_shape=(128, 128, 3)))
model.add(Conv2D(kernel_size=5, strides=1, filters=32, padding='same', activation='relu', name='conv1'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2, strides=2))
model.add(Conv2D(kernel_size=5, strides=1, filters=64, padding='same', activation='relu', name='conv2'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2, strides=2))
model.add(Conv2D(kernel_size=5, strides=1, filters=64, padding='same', activation='relu', name='conv3'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2, strides=2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

optimizer = Adam(lr=1e-3)

model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x=data, y=labels, epochs=5, batch_size=5)
result = model.evaluate(x=test_data, y=test_labels)
print('\n\nAccuracy:', result[1])
```

If I run it, I get the error `ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_3 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (10, 10, 2)`

I'm aware there are questions similar to this, but those questions haven't answered my question.
I've tried chaning the first Dense Layer neuron count, tried adding more max pools and conv layers, those didn't work out.

Comment: The labels need to be of dimensions ( n , 2 )

Comment: A single label holds 10 (x,y) coordinates, hence the shape is `(n, 10, 2)`. Should I flatten the labels?

Answer (score 0):

## The error is in this line:

```
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
```

## It should be:

```
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
```

## Reason

Because you have ten classes.